# rspec expect date to equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rspec

I have an object called a work order that has the following schema:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: work_orders
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  due_on             :date
#  name               :string(255)
```

I also have a Json output of the object when it is displayed:

```
{
   id: 1,
   due_on: "2015-06-08",
   name: "my work order"
}
```

I am attempting to use rspec to confirm that date displayed by the json, matches the date of the object. This is something I have done 50 times for other objects...

I have the following:

```
exemplar = FactoryGirl.create(:work_order)
...
puts "Test: #{exemplar.due_on}"
expect(exemplar.name).to      eq(hash['name'])   #This works fine!
expect(exemplar.due_on).to    eq(hash['due_on']) #This blows up...
```

The output I get is:

```
Test: 2015-06-08

expected: "2015-06-08"
     got: Mon, 08 Jun 2015
```

What I do not understand is where the "Mon, 08 Jun 2015" is coming from. when I print out the date with the puts statement, it shows it as 2015-06-08...

Comment: `exemplar.due_on` returns `2015-06-08`?

Comment: @Stefan it does when I use "puts" but in the 'expects' it gives me "Mon, 08 Jun 2015'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails converts the string to a date object. `2015-06-08` is the output from `Date#to_s`:

```
d = Date.today
#=> Thu, 17 Jul 2014

puts d
#=> 2014-07-17
```

You can compare the date object to your string with either:

```
expect(exemplar.due_on.to_s).to eq(hash['due_on'])
```

or:

```
expect(exemplar.due_on).to eq(Date.parse(hash['due_on']))
```

or using [Active Support Core Extensions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-string-conversions):

```
expect(exemplar.due_on).to eq(hash['due_on'].to_date)
```

Comment: any chance I could get your assistance with another Rspec question?

Comment: @Zack sure, but please open a new question

Comment: I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664034/custom-assert-message-for-multiple-expect-statements-within-match